# Facebook like - php code - set og:image

Tags: php, image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have facebook button on my site. It looks like:

```
<span class="fblike" style="float:right;padding-top:5px;margin-left:8px;">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
            {
                FB.init({appId: 'Your ID#', status: true, cookie: true,xfbml: true});
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/sk_SK/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
        </script>
        <fb:like layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="64" action="like" font="arial" colorscheme="light" />
</span>
```

My problem is, that I can't set og:image which I want :( whereever I place tag . It should be in  tag but there is no  in my default.php file. I'm working in joomla and it's one of my components.

Answer (score 1):

To display image of your choice on FB wall after all the intializations you should:

1. Replace your HTML tag with

   ```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
   ```
2. Add `og` tags in your head section:

   ```html
   <meta property="og:title" content="title of your page"/>
   <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
   <meta property="og:url" content="url of your page"/>
   <meta property="og:image" content="path of image u want to display"/>
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="name of your site"/>
   <meta property="og:description" content="some brief description about your page "/>
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="your fb app id"/>
   ```

After this you can check the data scrapped from your site using this [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

If there are no errors or warnings you are all set to use your *like* button.

Comment: I don't really understand what you r saying. I have default.php file, what should I put there to use og:image to work right? How should I replace my HTML tag with this code which u wrote?

Comment: Dear I m not sure what do u want. If you have a php page u must have html, head and body tag into it. If not then please add it. And place the above code there ....

Comment: There is no html, head, and body tags in my php file :/ it's joomlas component and there is also one file in called index.html but it's blank only with empty html and body tag (I tried to add head here and then og tags but nothing happend). And when I add head in my php, error shows up after refreshing my page

Comment: Now I addad <html><head></head><meta property="og:image" content="path of image I want to display"/></html> in the begining of my php file and nothing changes :/

Answer (score 0):

Open Graph meta tags should be in the `head` section and your HTML should be correct. First, be sure of that.

Use [this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check how facebook parses your website.

Comment: I wrote, that I have .php file so there's no head section

Comment: well, you should output a valid html, and put og tags to the head to be able to use them